# c# loop all method inside class and assign value

Tags: c#, winforms, ini, nini

I have a form with all button, label, I plan to make multi-language support by using INI files. I created Lang Class to hold value, if user change language, on-the-fly update without require restart the program.

my current code:

```
private  void  LangGet(string  LangID)
{
IConfigSource  Lng = new  IniConfigSource(Globals.Path.FolderLang  +  "\\"  +  LangID  +  ".ini");

  //  Set
  var  g = Lng.Configs["general"];
  Lang.Id.General.OK = g.GetString("OK");
  Lang.Id.General.Cancel = g.GetString("Cancel");
  Lang.Id.General.Error = g.GetString("Error");
  ...
  Lang.Id.General.lblStart = g.GetString("lblStart");
...
```

what I wanted code more efficient, but I dont know how...

```
IConfigSource Lng = new IniConfigSource(Globals.Path.FolderLang + "\\" + LangID + ".ini");
var g = Lng.Config["general"];
forloop ( ... )
{
    item = g.GetString(item);
}
```

if more powerful

```
IConfigSource Lng = new IniConfigSource(Globals.Path.FolderLang + "\\" + LangID + ".ini");
forloop ( ... )
{
    forloop ( ... )
    {
        TheName = Lng.Config[TheClass].GetString(TheName);
    }
}
```

After load INI loaded to Variable, time to control text get Variable value

```
forloop ( control )
{
    forloop ( class )
    {
        if ( control name contain btn )
        {
            item.Text = Lng.Configs[TheClass].GetString(item.name?);
        }
        if ( control name contain lbl )
        {
            item.Text = Lng.Configs[TheClass].GetString(item.name?);
        }
        // So On...
```

Comment: you need to use reflection. This lets you enumerate all the properties on an object and assign values

Comment: I tried this, it was half success to list all inside class, problem in second forloop... can't get next class name, here what I wrote: [main](http://pastebin.com/a9bqze6f) [class](http://pastebin.com/0NBWfdRP)

Comment: LOL... `INI Files`... I guess you're planning to run your application in Windows 3.1?

Comment: it's because easy to read... I used XML before, I ask someone to translate it, most of them confused, I send INI sample, that easy to read..

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer... so I answer my self,

using Ini-parser instead of Nini...

Make multi-language using INI file, allow language to be edited after compiled, easy to do correction.

Instead write code every control, use loop to do their job

CreateLang(); will scan all your form and it's child, using control Name as Ini Key

LoadLang(); will scan all your form control, once Ini Key equal control name, Value will apply to control.

During designing, all control must be change to {0} or multi-line {0}{1}{2}

Code:

```
    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateLang(); // Create new empty language
        //LoadLang(); // Load language, GUI must use {0} {1} ... as place-holder
    }

    private void LoadLang()
    {
        var parser = new FileIniDataParser();
        IniData data = parser.ReadFile("eng.ini");

        Control ctrl = this;
        do
        {
            ctrl = this.GetNextControl(ctrl, true);

            if (ctrl != null)
                if (ctrl is Label ||
                    ctrl is Button ||
                    ctrl is TabPage ||
                    ctrl is CheckBox)
                    if (data["Root"][ctrl.Name].Contains('|')) // Character | donated by New-Line, \n
                        ctrl.Text = String.Format(ctrl.Text, data["Root"][ctrl.Name].Split('|'));
                    else
                        ctrl.Text = String.Format(ctrl.Text, data["Root"][ctrl.Name]);

        } while (ctrl != null);

    }

    private void CreateLang()
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists("eng.ini"))
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("eng.ini", "");
        else
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("eng.ini", "");

        var parser = new FileIniDataParser();
        IniData data = parser.ReadFile("eng.ini");

        data.Sections.AddSection("Info");
        data.Sections["Info"].AddKey("Name", "Anime4000");
        data.Sections["Info"].AddKey("Version", "0.1");
        data.Sections["Info"].AddKey("Contact", "fb.com/anime4000");

        string main = "Root";
        data.Sections.AddSection(main);

        Control ctrl = this;
        do
        {
            ctrl = this.GetNextControl(ctrl, true);

            if (ctrl != null)
                if (ctrl is Label ||
                    ctrl is Button ||
                    ctrl is TabPage ||
                    ctrl is CheckBox ||
                    ctrl is GroupBox)
                    data.Sections[main].AddKey(ctrl.Name, "");

        } while (ctrl != null);


        parser.WriteFile("eng.ini", data);
    }
```